# when does classical theory of parabolic PDE fail

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am reading a paper on degenerate parabolic PDE and I am confused about the following statement.

" Diffusion coefficient is $mu^{m-1}$, and it vanishes when $u=0$. Hence at all those points where $u=0$ equation looses parabolicity, or degenerate, and accordingly **classical theory of uniformly parabolic equation is not applicable**

I don't understand this. What does classical theory of uniformly parabolic equation mean? How does it work? When does it fail?

Comment: Short semiserious answer: you do not need to know, since it fails in your case. Seriously: that commentary motivates the content that follows. (For a definition of *uniformly parabolic PDE*, at least in the linear case, see Evans's book, chapter 7).

Comment: i think the author of that paper meant regularisation, which is in the classical theory of parabolic pde in the sense of ladyzhenskaya "linear and quasi-linear equations of parabolic types. On the other hand, the classical parabolic theory in Chapt 7 in Evans doesn't seem to have any problems use regularisation.